# ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26 installation errror

Tags: ruby, ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to get ruby-debug working with ruby 1.9.3 and rails on OSX Lion. 
I've been following http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug , but my problem is I can't get ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem

In my .Gemfile for sources i have

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'    
source :rubyforge     
source 'http://gems.rubyforge.org'
```

when I do

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby- include=/Users/minadoroudi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/
or 
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26 -- --with-ruby- include=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem' (>= 0) in any repository
0ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ruby-debug-base19, ruby-debug-base19x
```

Looks like it doesn't pick rubyforge, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to type `gem install ruby-debug-base19` to install the latest version of ruby-debug-base-19.
If you absolutely need to have version *0.11.26*, use the `v` switch, like so:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v 0.11.26
```

Comment: thanks, so the problem is 0.11.26 is on rubyforge.org and my gemfile seems like it doesn't pick rubyforge and only looks at rubygems.org, even though I added it to my .Gemfile, so I'm wondering if anybody has any idea how to force it.

Comment: actually I think I found out, I need to download ruby-debug-base19 locally from ruby forge and do Gem install on the file. thanks anyways :)