# Unable to find a valid gem for ruby-debug-base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the `ruby-debug` gem, requiring `ruby-debug-base` as a dependency.

`gem install ruby-debug` errors out with:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'ruby-debug-base' (~> 0.10.6.0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ruby-debug-base
```

Ruby version: 2.3.1, `which ruby` prints:

```
/Users/my-name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
```

have tried adding

```
source :rubyforge     
source 'http://gems.rubyforge.org'
```

to my Gemfile, [as seen in a similar question, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935772/ruby-debug-base19-0-11-26-installation-errror).

When I try installing an older version of the gem using `gem install ruby-debug -v 0.10.5.rc9`, I get the error:

`Ruby version 2.3.1 is too new`

I've tried installing just `ruby-debug-base`, and am met with the error:

```
    current directory: /Users/my-name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/linecache-1.3.1/ext/linecache
/Users/my-name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170824-39487-dus4av.rb extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `gem 'debugger'` in Gemfile or install it just for development.

```
group :development do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

> Only 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 are supported. For 2.X rubies, consider using
>   [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

Even the maintainer of the debugger gem makes this recommendation. Look [here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger#known-issues).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it didn't work. running `gem install debugger` failed with the error: /Users/my-name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./231/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: well that doesn't work because the `debugger` gem isn't installed

Comment: seems like debugger doesn't work well with ruby 2.x, try replaced `debugger` with `byebug` .

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. Thanks a lot for the help; I'll use a different debugger.

Comment: @matthewninja refer to my updated answer. Even the maintainer of the debugger gem recommend to use byebug for ruby 2.x .